# How can i get all files on disk with a specific extension using 'Directory.getFiles' and save them in a list

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I'm doing a console project whose goal is to search the entire disk for all files with the extension '.config'

I've tried something like:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
  {
   Console.WriteLine(file);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

but gave me an error "denied access to path (...)".

On the internet I found this code:

```
Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
        pending.Push("C:\\");

        while (pending.Count != 0)
        {
            var path = pending.Pop();
            string[] next = null;

            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.config");
            }
            catch { }

            if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
                foreach (var file in next)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

but it just shows the path clicking always in 'enter' and I want to save those files/path in a list.

Someone can help?

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree

Comment: "but it just shows the path clicking always in 'enter' " this is because you have this line: `Console.ReadLine();` in there. Substitude this line for a `myList.Add(file)` and you should be finished. If you write : "save them in a list" then you should at least have a list to save them ;)

Comment: off topic: you really should avoid empty catch clauses. Sending error messages into oblivion is not going to help you to understand what went wrong

Comment: @EylM okay, I will see it

Comment: @MongZhu I've tried to add to a list, but when I try to show this list on console, the console is clean

Comment: you need to do probably way more error trapping. your foreach subdir, if denied will not do any more subdirectories after that, this is a common piece of recursion code that many of us have done something similar.

Comment: @BugFinder: The Directory.GetDirectories should only throw an UnauthorizedAccessException if the access to the parent directory is forbidden. The foreach subdir only runs over a bunch of strings without accessing the directories/files of that string, thus shouldn't throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do to improve that code:

1. Use `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()` to avoid making a copy of the names of all the files in each directory.
2. Make the return type of the method `IEnumerable<string>` to make it easier to consume.

We also need to be very careful about exceptions caused by attempting to access protected files and directories. The code below is also complicated by the fact that you're not allowed to `yield return` from inside a `try/catch` block, so we have to rearrange the code somewhat.

(Also note that we have to dispose the enumerator returned from `.GetEnumerator()`; normally this is done automatically when you use `foreach`, but in this case we can't - because of having to avoid doing `yield return` in a `try/catch` - so we have to use `using` to dispose it.)

Here's a modification of your original code to do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string spec)
{
    var pending = new Stack<string>(new []{root});

    while (pending.Count > 0)
    {
        var path = pending.Pop();
        IEnumerator<string> fileIterator = null;

        try
        {
            fileIterator = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, spec).GetEnumerator();
        }

        catch {}

        if (fileIterator != null)
        {
            using (fileIterator)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!fileIterator.MoveNext()) // Throws if file is not accessible.
                            break;
                    }

                    catch { break; }

                    yield return fileIterator.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator<string> dirIterator = null;

        try
        {
            dirIterator = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).GetEnumerator();
        }

        catch {}

        if (dirIterator != null)
        {
            using (dirIterator)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!dirIterator.MoveNext()) // Throws if directory is not accessible.
                            break;
                    }

                    catch { break; }

                    pending.Push(dirIterator.Current);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an example, here's how you could use a console app to list all the accessible ".txt" files on the "C:\" drive:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (var file in GetFiles("C:\\", "*.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: what 'root' means?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista `root` is the root folder that you want to start finding files at - so "C:\" for all files in and under C:\ and "C:\Windows" for all files in and under "C:\Windows".

Comment: @Catarina what if we want to shear in whole HDD ??? like find all of files with .txt in all Drives .

Comment: @ImanS3 Maybe you need to check what the disk's "identification" is, probably is the disk D:\\ and change from `GetFiles("C:\\", "*.txt")` to `GetFiles("D:\\", "*.txt")`. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the lines

```
Console.WriteLine(file);
Console.ReadLine();
```

with a method to store them in a list.
For example

```
foundFiles.Add(file);
```

Then when the method is done, you can read all found file paths from this list.

*Notes:*
This will not yield **all** files on the system that match the filter.
Only files where your application has access to their respective directory are found this way.
For example the Windows directory and user directories of other users are usually protected. (assuming you run on Windows)

Keep in mind, that some files might be protected independently of their directory.
So when trying to read them, also consider the fact, that the read might fail.
Just encompass the read with a try catch.

Comment: Thank you for the notes :) I tried to add in a list but when I try to show this list on console, the console is clean, don't show nothing

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error "denied access to path (...)", sometimes you have to run Visual Studio as an a administrator in order to access some folders in the C:\ drive.

Comment: yes, I also tried to run as an a administrator but doesn't work for me